# Passing POST params to NodeJS from fetch API

Tags: node.js, fetch

When I send fetch request from my React app NodeJS server doesn't receive any params...

React:

```
fetch('http://xxx:5000/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ 'url': 'admin@domain.com', 'password': '12345' }) // formData
    })
```

NodeJS:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

const app = express()
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, async (req, resp, next) => {
  const url = req.body.url

  console.log(url) // undefined
  const urlIdPattern = /\d+/g
}
```

When I send request directly from form tag it works correctly

```
<form action="xxx" method="POST">
  <input name="url">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong parser. Since you are sending the data as `application/json`, you should be using `json` from `body-parser` instead of `urlencoded`.

You should use it like this (to apply it globally).

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json();
```

Or like this, if you want to apply the middleware to that specific route.

```
app.post('/', bodyParser.json(), async (req, resp, next) => {...
```

> When I send request directly from form tag it works correctly

That is because when you submit a form, data is sent as `urlencoded` (not as `application/json`).

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/', async (req, resp, next) => {
  const url = req.body.url

  console.log(url) // undefined
  const urlIdPattern = /\d+/g
}
```